# Eclipse Dialogs Have No Title Bar and Can't Be Moved in Gnome 3

Tags: eclipse, gnome, gnome-3

I just installed Eclipse from the Android website and the dialogs have no title bar and seem to be docked at the top of the Eclipse main window. I can't find a way to move them or get the titlebar back. I'm using Gnome 3 as desktop/window manager.

For example, if I choose Search | File... from the main menu, it comes up, but without titlebar. If I press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>, I can move the entire window, but the dialog will not move relative to the window.

How do I fix this?

Thx.

Comment: Has nothing to do with eclipse, but with Gnome defaults. Every modal dialog behaves that way. Therefore, added tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are missing an important information, your operating system and desktop environment. Let me guess? Linux/Gnome? Or Cinnamon?

Gnome has the, erm, great feature to attach modal dialogs at the main window.

You can install `dconf-editor` and set the key `org/gnome/shell/overrides/attach-modal-dialogs` to `false`.

In Cinnamon you can easily disable this feature in the `System Settings > Windows > Attach dialog windows` (may not be the actual text as I translated it from my locale). You need to switch the settings to *Expert mode* to see the *Windows* entry.

Comment: Cinnamon. Didn't know that would be important.

Comment: So, it's a feature. Yickkk... Okay, I won't keep fighting. Thanks.

Comment: In Cinnamon it can easily be disabled in the settings.

Comment: After spending literally hours on that annoying Gnome design flaw, perhaps someone will find this helpful: On [SLED 12](https://www.suse.com/releasenotes/x86_64/SUSE-SLED/12/), they chose to introduce yet another, additional location for the `attach modal dialog` option. In `dconf-editor`, under `org.gnome.shell.extensions.classic-overrides`, there's `attach-modal-dialogs` **again** - you have to disable it there, too. I found this after doing `CTRL-F` in `dconf-editor`, so you might want to consider doing the same when you're not sure how your distribution of choice handles Gnome settings.